# Copy project to root in TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

In teamcity 8 there is a button to Copy project. When I click it I get a modal window where I need to choose a new name and id. And also I have to select value from "Copy to project" dropdown. But I don't need to copy my project to another, I just need it to be in the root. And there is no root project in this dropdown list. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be a Project Administrator on the **Root** Project or a System Administrator if you want to copy into / add a project to the Root Project.